# SSIS: Insert/Update

Tags: ssis, etl, insert-update

I am wondering if there is a specific Insert or Update option in SSIS.

Will I have to do some coding if I want to let the program check if it is an update or insert? 
Or can there be an option enabled so it will check itself if the PK exists then update and otherwise insert?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one solution 
[SSIS update insert](http://itssmee.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/ssis-insert-and-update-rows-in-a-table-based-on-the-contents-of-a-excel-file/)

[better update syntax](http://beingoyen.blogspot.com/2010/03/ssis-how-to-update-instead-of-insert.html)

If there are more records it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks. I found that solution on the internet, but on Talend (open source ETL tool) you have an option to say 'Insert or Update' so you don't have to build the logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I uderstand your problem properly. But I think SQL Server `MERGE` would be very useful here. And it's super-efficent.

More info here:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx